# Length of audio after entering url

Tags: jquery, audio

I have created a box in which i will enter the link of the audio tag and then after clicking submit i need the length of the audio.
But if i am giving static url then its giving the length in return but when i am using this method of text box it not showing the length please help.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="mp_source">
<input type="button" id="save" value="save">
<audio id="track" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source id="sourceMp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
<p id="time"></p>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#save").click(function(){
var get_source = $("#mp_source").val();
$("#sourceMp3").attr('src',get_source);
myFunction();
});
});
</script>
<script>


function
myFunction() { 
var vid = document.getElementById("track");
var len = vid.duration/60;
var n = len.toFixed(2);
 var res = n.split(".");
 var result = res[0]+':'+res[1];
 document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = result;
} 
</script>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8epuqnv/1/) example for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  var url = document.querySelector('input').value;
  
  // create new audio to get the data from the file
  var audio = new Audio();
  
  // listen to the event that the broswer done to read the file 
  audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',   function(e) {
    
    // get the duration from the track
    var duration = e.path[0].duration;
    console.log(duration);
    document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = duration + 's';
  });
  
  audio.src = url;
  //audio.play();
};
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type url here" value="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" />
<button>Go</button>
<hr />
<div id="result"></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/xicixo